# Getting error when i run ./network.sh createChannel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efzva.png)

I want to run the test network of hyper ledger fabric.
./network.sh up run all the containers but after running the ./network.sh createChannel gave me "Anchor peer update failed error"

Comment: Could you please give more context of your question? For example, whats in `network.sh`?

Comment: I turn off the proxy, and it ran.
Thanks for help

Comment: Sure. Consider writing an answer documenting how you fixed the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I set the proxy on vagrant that's why this issue has created.
I turn it off, and again run the network, and it ran.